# Use different form fields in javascript script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which retrieves data from an API using Ajax. Right now it's working perfectly fine like it should. The current form looks like this:

```
<input id="search" type="text" autocomplete="on" name="query" placeholder="Zoek op handelsnaam" class="form-control">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="handelsnaam" name="handelsnaam" placeholder="Handelsnaam">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script src="/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/js/script1.js"></script>
```

Now instead of the above input fields , I would like to use my own input fields instead. The fields I want to use look slightly different. Mine look like :

```
//field 1 aka search   
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_myfield15" id="billing_myfield15" placeholder="" value="handelsnaam">

//field2 
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_myfield16" id="billing_myfield16" placeholder="" value="">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script> 
<script src="/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/js/script1.js"></script>
```

Seeing these fields have different id's / classes this means i would have to edit my javascript file and adjust a few things. I tried this but for me it didnt work. How do i modify the current script1.js file so it works with the new fields?

My javascript file looks like this (note that this is the working one):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#search").autocomplete({

        source: function( request, response ) {

            $.ajax({

                url: "/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/api/openkvk.php",

                dataType: "json",

                data: {

                    'q' : request.term,

                },

                type: 'POST',

                success: function( data ) {

                    response($.map(data.handelsnaam, function (item) {

                        return {

                            label: [item.handelsnaam, item.dossiernummer, item.plaats].join(' - '),

                            value: [item.handelsnaam, item.dossiernummer, item.plaats].join(' - '),

                            link: item.link

                        };

                    }));

                }

            });

        },

        minLength: 1,

        select: function( event, ui ) {

            if (ui.item){

            $.ajax({

                url: "/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/api/openkvk.php",

                data: {

                    'id' : ui.item.link,

                },

                type: 'POST',

                success: function(data) {

                    $("#handelsnaam").val([data.handelsnaam]);
                },

                error: function() {



                },

            }) 

            }

        },

        open: function() {

            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );

        },

        close: function() {

            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );

        }

    });

});
```

I tried it myself aand changed a few things in the javascript file. Mine ended up looking like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#billing_myfield15").autocomplete({

        source: function( request, response ) {

            $.ajax({

                url: "/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/api/openkvk.php",

                dataType: "json",

                data: {

                    'q' : request.term,

                },

                type: 'POST',

                success: function( data ) {

                    response($.map(data.handelsnaam, function (item) {

                        return {

                            label: [item.handelsnaam, item.dossiernummer, item.plaats].join(' - '),

                            value: [item.handelsnaam, item.dossiernummer, item.plaats].join(' - '),

                            link: item.link

                        };

                    }));

                }

            });

        },

        minLength: 1,

        select: function( event, ui ) {

            if (ui.item){

            $.ajax({

                url: "/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/api/openkvk.php",

                data: {

                    'id' : ui.item.link,

                },

                type: 'POST',

                success: function(data) {

                    $("#billing_myfield16").val([data.handelsnaam]);
                },

                error: function() {



                },

            }) 

            }

        },

        open: function() {

            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );

        },

        close: function() {

            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );

        }

    });

});
```

There's also a PHP file.

```
<?php

$key = "secret";

if(isset($_REQUEST["q"])){
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    suggest($q, $key);
}

if(isset($_REQUEST["id"])){
    $id = $_REQUEST["id"];
    getCompany($id, $key);
}


function getCompany($id, $key){
    $url = "https://api.overheid.io".$id;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'ovio-api-key: '.$key));

    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header('content-type: application/json');
    echo $result;
}

function suggest($q, $key){
    $url = "https://api.overheid.io/suggest/openkvk/".$q."?size=25&fields[]=handelsnaam";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'ovio-api-key: '.$key));

    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header('content-type: application/json');
    echo $result;
}


?>
```

Comment: Apparently my script worked all this time, but I had cache issues so i didnt see any results.